# Calling a service in C++ without write it on terminal

Tags: ros, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanna clear my turtlesim path when I press a specific button of my joystick,  like when I write it on terminal: **rosservice call clear** .

Afterwards, I wanna do the same idea but changing the background like **rosparam set background-r 150**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Joy.h>

#include <ros/service.h>

class TeleopTurtle
{
public:
  TeleopTurtle();

private:
  void joyCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy);
  
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;

  int linear_, angular_;
  double l_scale_, a_scale_;
  ros::Publisher vel_pub_;
  ros::Subscriber joy_sub_;
  
};

TeleopTurtle::TeleopTurtle():
  linear_(1),
  angular_(2)
{

  nh_.param("axis_linear", linear_, linear_);
  nh_.param("axis_angular", angular_, angular_);
  nh_.param("scale_angular", a_scale_, a_scale_);
  nh_.param("scale_linear", l_scale_, l_scale_);

  vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle1/cmd_vel", 1);
  joy_sub_ = nh_.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("joy", 10, &TeleopTurtle::joyCallback, this);

}

void TeleopTurtle::joyCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy)
{
  geometry_msgs::Twist twist;
  twist.linear.x = l_scale_*joy->axes[linear_];
  twist.angular.z = a_scale_*joy->axes[angular_];
  vel_pub_.publish(twist);
  if (joy->buttons[2] == 1)
  {
   //ros::service::call(clear);  // Call service:  rosservice call clear
   } 


}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "teleop_turtle");
  TeleopTurtle teleop_turtle;      
     
  ros::spin();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194399/calling-a-service-in-c++-without-write-it-on-terminal/) by [astur](https://answers.ros.org/users/20087/astur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-07**:
All this is possible, but what is your question?

**Comment by [astur](https://answers.ros.org/users/20087/astur/) on 2014-10-07**:
Calling a ros service (rosservice call clear) in C++ without write it on terminal when i press a specific button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_the_Client_Node), please research in the future.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [astur](https://answers.ros.org/users/20087/astur/) on 2014-10-07**:
Sorry I lacked: without write it on terminal.
I checked all tutorials and some answers like http://answers.ros.org/question/12661/using-rosservicecall/

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-07**:
You should work through all the beginner tutorials listed [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), it will save you a lot of trouble down the line.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is simple code to do this, adapted from the examples at [A Gentle Introduction to ROS](https://www.cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/).
The last three lines are key, since they call the service.  Remember to #include the relevant .h file for the service you are using.

```
// This program waits for the clear service to be available
// (potentially waiting for turtlesim to start up), and
// clears the screen.
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_srvs/Empty.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "clear_screen");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // Wait until the clear service is available, which
  // indicates that turtlesim has started up, and has
  // set the background color parameters.
  ros::service::waitForService("clear");  //this is optional

  // Get turtlesim to pick up the new parameter values.
  ros::ServiceClient clearClient
    = nh.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/clear");
  std_srvs::Empty srv;
  clearClient.call(srv);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [AaronBecker](https://answers.ros.org/users/33464/aaronbecker/) with karma: 11 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1